# Can't (.exe) my 300 line program using Cx_freeze or PyInstaller. (Matplotlib/Scipy)

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, scipy, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

I created my very first Python program for work and I have it running in PyCharm.

The program has a GUI, it basically pops up a window, has a directory tree so the user can select a jpg file, it then binarizes the image then lets the user select the binary threshold with a slider. It also displays two other images that I perform image transformations on.

SO, my problem is that I cannot build it to an .exe at all. I've tried Py2Exe, PyInstaller, and CX_freeze. I've tried building my own .spec files in Pyinstaller, but all have no success.

I'm running 2.7.6. I initially had 64 bit Python installed so I uninstalled everything Python related and installed 32 bit Python.

Initially when I was using pyinstaller I would just get ImportError: %1 is not a valid Win32 application, **however since building a .spec file now I get actual errors**. I've tried using hooks (hiddenimports=["wx", "scipy", "skimage", "matplotlib", "numpy"]) to make sure all the right files are included, but still no luck.

The main error that I'm receiving right now is: File "_ufuncs.pyx", line 1, in init scipy.special._ufuncs(scipy\special_ufuncs.c:19992) ImportError: No module named _ufuncs_cxx

I also created a smaller code below that just pops up a Wx window with a plot inside, but I receive the same error there.

Like I mentioned, I'm new to Python, and I've done a lot of reading and haven't been able to figure this out.  I've spent probably 10-20 hours just trying to get it to compile correctly.

**Below isn't my actual program, but a small snippet using wxPython and MatPlotLib that produces the same error**.

This is the sample code:

```
import wx
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("WXAgg")
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import     FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigCanvas#,NavigationToolbar2WxAgg as NavigationToolbar
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy
from scipy import interpolate
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import NavigationToolbar2Wx


from skimage.filter.rank import entropy
from skimage.morphology import disk
from skimage.util import img_as_ubyte
from skimage import color
from skimage import io
import skimage

from numpy import arange, sin, pi

class CanvasPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.figure = Figure()
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Fit()

    def draw(self):
        t = arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.01)
        s = sin(2 * pi * t)
        self.axes.plot(t, s)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    fr = wx.Frame(None, title='test')
    panel = CanvasPanel(fr)
    panel.draw()
    fr.Show()
```

**This is the error I receive:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 11, in <module>
  File "c:\python27_32bit\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg\PyInstalle\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in
 load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\users\iolvera\PycharmProjects\EL and Grayscale Analyzer\build\compilertest\out00-PYZ.pyz\scipy.interpolate",line 156, in <module>
  File "c:\python27_32bit\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\users\iolvera\PycharmProjects\EL and Grayscale Analyzer\build\compilertest\out00-PYZ.pyz\scipy.interpolate.interpolate", line 12, in <module>
  File "c:\python27_32bit\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module 
   exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "C:\users\iolvera\PycharmProjects\EL and Grayscale Analyzer\build\compilertest\out00-PYZ.pyz\scipy.special", line 531, in <module>
  File "c:\python27_32bit\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 409, in load_module
    module = imp.load_module(fullname, fp, filename, self._c_ext_tuple)
  File "_ufuncs.pyx", line 1, in init scipy.special._ufuncs (scipy\special\_ufuncs.c:19992)
ImportError: No module named _ufuncs_cxx
```

My Python Path is correct C:\Python27_32bit\ and I also have \lib\site-packages\ and \DLL included correctly.

Like I mentioned, both programs run correctly in PyCharm.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: The issue is coming out of numpy c-extensions.  Hopefully that points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, and I fixed it in py2exe by specifically telling it to include the offending module. So, in `setup.py`:

```
includes = ['scipy.special._ufuncs_cxx']

setup(...,
      options={"py2exe":{"includes":includes}}
     )
```

I had this happen with a couple of other SciPy modules, too, so my `includes` list has about six things in it.